# How do I upgrade my software to v0.11.0.0?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monero-wallet-gui, update

I've been running CLI v0.10.3.1 and GUI Beta 2. How do I update these to v0.11.0.0?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**CLI:**

If you are using the CLI you ought to perform the following steps:

1. Download the new binaries from [here](https://getmonero.org/downloads/).
2. Extract the new binaries to a new directory of your liking.
3. Copy over the wallet files from the old directory (the one that contains the v0.10.3.1 binaries).

Note that a blockchain resync is **not** needed. If you open `monerod-v.0.11.0.0` it simply picks up where it left off.

---

**GUI:**

If you are using the GUI you ought to perform the following steps:

1. Download the new binaries from [here](https://getmonero.org/downloads/).
2. Extract the new binaries to a new directory of your liking.
3. Open `monero-wallet-gui`^1. It should automatically load your "old" wallet.

(1) On Linux you ought to start the GUI with the `start-gui.sh` script.

Comment: for the CLI I'm getting permission denied. see question https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6971/monero-v0-11-1-0-cli-permission-denied

Comment: Responded there.