# XMR Blockchain NOT syncing beyond a particular Block 1400001

Tags: monerod, monero-wallet-gui, blockchain, mymonero

On my windows 10 it took many days and bandwidth (150 GB) to download XMR blockchain which stands at 29 GB.

When I login to lite portal mymonero.com and I can see my balance as 0.835. But in Monero GUI it shows as
0.035 . Looks like it is not synced properly however on network it shows connected.

I went to cmd and ran status. Looks like stuck on block 14000001.

monerod status
2017-10-03 14:34:49.478 15852   INFO    global  contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:145
New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,stacktrace:INFO
Height: 1400001/1400001 (100.0%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash 259.32 MH/s, v5, update needed, 7(out)+0(in) connections, uptime 0d 0h 7m 40s

I've done below :
1) Stope GUI. Make sure no deamon process is running in taskmgr
2) Rename p2pstate.binx to p2pstate.binx

Restarted GUI. Still balances are not catching up.
Then I tried from cmd

C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\monero-gui-win-x64-v0.10.3.1\monero-gui-0.10.3.1-beta2>monerod.exe --data-dir E:\MoneroBlockchain

2017-10-03 14:43:33.854 13748   INFO    global  contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:145
New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,stacktrace:INFO
2017-10-03 14:43:33.869 13748   INFO    global  src/daemon/main.cpp:282 Monero 'Wolfram Warptangent' (v0.10.3.1-release)
2017-10-03 14:43:33.869 13748   INFO    global  src/daemon/protocol.h:55
Initializing cryptonote protocol...
2017-10-03 14:43:33.885 13748   INFO    global  src/daemon/protocol.h:60
Cryptonote protocol initialized OK
2017-10-03 14:43:33.885 13748   INFO    global  src/daemon/p2p.h:63     Initializing p2p server...
2017-10-03 14:43:35.729 13748   INFO    global  src/daemon/p2p.h:68     P2p server initialized OK
2017-10-03 14:43:35.729 13748   INFO    global  src/daemon/rpc.h:58     Initializing core rpc server...
2017-10-03 14:43:35.744 13748   INFO    global  contrib/epee/include/net/http_server_impl_base.h:70     Binding on 127.0.0.1:18081
2017-10-03 14:43:35.744 13748   INFO    global  src/daemon/rpc.h:63     Core rpc server initialized OK on port: 18081
2017-10-03 14:43:35.744 13748   INFO    global  src/daemon/core.h:73    Initializing core...
2017-10-03 14:43:36.985 13748   INFO    global  src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:326     Loading blockchain from folder E:\MoneroBlockchain\lmdb ...
2017-10-03 14:43:39.009 13748   WARN    net.dns src/common/dns_utils.cpp:531
WARNING: no two valid MoneroPulse DNS checkpoint records were received
2017-10-03 14:43:39.025 13748   INFO    global  src/daemon/core.h:78    Core initialized OK
2017-10-03 14:43:39.025 13748   INFO    global  src/daemon/rpc.h:68     Starting core rpc server...
2017-10-03 14:43:39.041 [SRV_MAIN]      INFO    global  src/daemon/rpc.h:73
Core rpc server started ok
2017-10-03 14:43:39.041 [SRV_MAIN]      INFO    global  src/daemon/p2p.h:78
Starting p2p net loop...
2017-10-03 14:43:40.041 [P2P7]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:1098

---

The daemon will start synchronizing with the network. It may take up to several hours.

You can set the level of process detailization* through "set_log " command*,
where  is between 0 (no details) and 4 (very verbose), or custom category based levels (eg, *:WARNING)

Use the "help" command to see the list of available commands.

---

2017-10-03 14:43:40.041 [P2P7]  WARN    global  src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:1122    **********************************************************************
2017-10-03 14:43:40.056 [P2P7]  WARN    global  src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:1123    Last scheduled hard fork time shows a daemon update is needed now.
2017-10-03 14:43:40.072 [P2P7]  WARN    global  src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:1124    **********************************************************************
2017-10-03 14:43:40.721 [P2P7]  WARN    net.dns src/common/dns_utils.cpp:531
WARNING: no two valid MoneroPulse DNS checkpoint records were received
2017-10-03 14:43:41.659 [P2P9]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:1115

---

You are now synchronized with the network. You may now start monero-wallet-cli.

Use the "help" command to see the list of available commands.

---

2017-10-03 14:46:27.468 [P2P7]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:293     [213.239.196.214:8180 OUT] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 1400001 -> 1412471 [Your node is 12470 blocks (17 days) behind]
SYNCHRONIZATION started
2017-10-03 14:48:42.358 [P2P8]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:293     [176.9.147.178:8180 OUT] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 1400001 -> 1412472 [Your node is 12471 blocks (17 days) behind]
SYNCHRONIZATION started

It is NOT syncing beyong a particular Block 1400001  .
Stuck at 1400001 from 7 hours.

Please help!

Thanks,

Comment: `C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\monero-gui-win-x64-v0.10.3.1\monero-gui-0.10.3.1-beta2>monerod.exe --data-dir E:\MoneroBlockchain` indicates that you're using an outdated version. Please upgrade first: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6056/how-do-i-upgrade-my-software-to-v0-11-0-0

Answer (score 4):

There was a protocol upgrade recently, and you're using an old version. Upgrade to latest version and it will continue syncing.

[How do I upgrade my software to v0.11.0.0?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6056/how-do-i-upgrade-my-software-to-v0-11-0-0)