# Thought Gui wallet receiving problem solved, but now have other problems

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

Shit getting old.

Bothering you again, Kind user36303- 
So wallet is "Synchronizing" --- but stuck on 21,895 blocks.

I opened  Settings/ Manage daemon / show status. 
This comes up in daemon log new window:

2017-10-17 15:33:13.543     INFO    global  contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:145   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,stacktrace:INFO
Height: 1400001/1421896 (98.5%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash 259.32 MH/s, v5, update needed, 0(out)+0(in) connections, uptime 6d 3h 10m 4s

Any thoughts on wtf is problem NOW?

Comment: Can you check if your transaction actually arrived? https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6137/how-do-i-as-a-recipient-verify-that-my-transaction-actually-arrived

Comment: No, it did not arrive.

Comment: Can you post the transaction ID here?

Comment: e9ad3fd4cccb98d00bda85de9c6b2113e6fd154b3dc5cc43edae932215fbf99f

Comment: b4e5860573acc2927b1edd3c79640e864c09e1b8554b9cdf5aa962e88cc6971a

Comment: Those both weren't sent out, see. Enter them [here](https://xmrchain.net) and you'll see that they aren't present in the blockchain. I'd advise to contact Bittrex' support.

Comment: These two aren't valid hashes. They have three extra characters. You either did not copy them correctly, or bittrex went wonky.

Comment: That's very interesting. The hashes in the URLs in your edit seem fine. The ones you pasted in the comments above are not. They look the same, but have the extra characters near the end, representing a zero width space (which is why it looks the same to the eye). This is probably a quirk of software, email, editor, or stack exchange. Anyway, this was a red herring, and I see the txs are on the chain, so you need to ensure both monerod and the wallet are both synced. Try "status" in monerod and monero-wallet-cli (or in the GUI, check the bottom left corner message doesn't say "syncing" or so).

Comment: Your new problem seems to be you might be running version 0.10.3.1, which is too old to get past the last fork. If so, use 0.11.0.0. Even better, use https://build.getmonero.org/downloads/monero-e51990be-win64.tar.gz which has fixes for other syncing problems you might run into.

Comment: As user36303 said, you're likely running an old version, which causes you to get "stuck" on block 1400001. You can use this to properly upgrade: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6056/how-do-i-upgrade-my-software-to-v0-11-0-0